# Running process start time

Tags: android

I am using below code to get all currently running process's on device. How can I get running process start time?

```
    activityMan = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    process = activityMan.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (Iterator iterator = process.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = (RunningAppProcessInfo) iterator
                .next();
        pSname= runningAppProcessInfo.processName;
        System.out.println(pSname);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe  you'll find that helpfull:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677229/how-to-find-out-the-running-start-time-of-android-application

Answer (score 3):

This will return process start time (since system boot):

```
private static long getStartTime(final int pid) throws IOException {
    final String path = "/proc/" + pid + "/stat";
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    final String stat;
    try {
        stat = reader.readLine();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    final String field2End = ") ";
    final String fieldSep = " ";
    final int fieldStartTime = 20;
    final int msInSec = 1000;
    try {
        final String[] fields = stat.substring(stat.lastIndexOf(field2End)).split(fieldSep);
        final long t = Long.parseLong(fields[fieldStartTime]);
        final int tckName = Class.forName("libcore.io.OsConstants").getField("_SC_CLK_TCK").getInt(null);
        final Object os = Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore").getField("os").get(null);
        final long tck = (Long)os.getClass().getMethod("sysconf", Integer.TYPE).invoke(os, tckName);
        return t * msInSec / tck;
    } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } catch (final IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

To get process running time:

```
final long dt = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - getStartTime(Process.myPid());
```

Comment: this failed on some phone, since Android N, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37091475，is there a new way?

Comment: This doesn't give every time correct start time for the process especially for Samsung devices.

Answer (score 3):

With kotlin and API 21 the above code becomes

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getStartTime( pid:Int ) : Long { 
    val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader ("/proc/$pid/stat"));
    val stats = try {
        reader.readLine();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    val fieldStartTime = 20;
    val msInSec = 1000;
    try {
        val fields = stats.substring (stats.lastIndexOf(") ")).split(" ");
        val t = fields[fieldStartTime].toLong();
        val tck = Os.sysconf(OsConstants._SC_CLK_TCK);
        return (t * msInSec) / tck;
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        throw IOException (e);
    } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException ) {
        throw IOException (e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

supplement for the above answer..

```
private static long getProcessStartTime(final int pid) throws Exception {
    final String path = "/proc/" + pid + "/stat";
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    final String stat;
    try {
        stat = reader.readLine();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    final String field2End = ") ";
    final String fieldSep = " ";
    final int fieldStartTime = 20;
    final int msInSec = 1000;
    try {
        final String[] fields = stat.substring(stat.lastIndexOf(field2End)).split(fieldSep);
        final long t = Long.parseLong(fields[fieldStartTime]);
        int tckName;
        try {
            tckName = Class.forName("android.system.OsConstants").getField("_SC_CLK_TCK").getInt(null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            tckName = Class.forName("libcore.io.OsConstants").getField("_SC_CLK_TCK").getInt(null);
        }

        final Object os = Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore").getField("os").get(null);
        final long tck = (Long)os.getClass().getMethod("sysconf", Integer.TYPE).invoke(os, tckName);
        return t * msInSec / tck;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only receive this information from a service. Take a look at the [documentation of ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html) or [activeSince attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#activeSince)

Comment: In RunningServiceInfo they have only lastActivityTime. But i want the time when this process get started. Is lastActivityTime and process start time are same?

Comment: they have also `activeSince`, link in the answer

Comment: activeSince is in RunningServiceInfo.. see my original question. I am asking about RunningAppProcessInfo.

Comment: @Ajay And as my answer mentioned, there is only an information available for services, please read my first sentence...