# Android: reading started time of Running Application. Is it only possible for Services?

Tags: android

I am able to read the started time of a running Service using this :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningServiceInfo> services = am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
    activeTime=info.activeSince;
}
```

But i **could not** find option to read started time of running Application

Here is my Code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks= am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (RunningTaskInfo info : tasks) {
    //HOW TO GET started time ??
}
```

My question is :
**How to read started time of a Running App? Is this option really not available for running Application ?**

I have seen some app(installed in my phone) are displaying started time of a Application.

I googled about it, see some QA on SO. But could not found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another questions like yours
[Running process start time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552125/running-process-start-time)

No way to read start time of app from APIs. Only possible for services through API.

I think the time you are seeing is the activeSince. The app probably has a service and therefore you are seeing the activeSince.