# I want to get the time of starting an application

Tags: android, process

I want to get the starting time of the running application process

is it possible or not

thanks

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552125/running-process-start-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677229/how-to-find-out-the-running-start-time-of-android-application

Comment: How do you want the time, as Log statement or Toast or some other way?

Comment: @sekhar , did u get any idea how can we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value from the **System.getCurrentTimeMillis()** at the beginning of your first activity and use it for your purpose.

Comment: but i want to get the running applications process start time

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application for this. In Application you will have oncreate That is the exact Application Launching time. its also like as Activity only.

```
public class Ap extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

in manifest you need to add this as like as follow

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="Ap"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: but i want to get the running applications process start time